# nativescript tabview actionbar nested

Tags: navigation, nested, android-actionbar, nativescript, tabview

I have 4 tabs and I'm using router-outlet for the "navigation" within each tab.
I wanted to ask you if you can create different actionbar for each tab and if you can navigate within the tabs also changing the title and the items of the actionbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by creating for each component of the four tab an actionbar and navigating in the desired tab according to the tab selected, example:

```
public onIndexChanged(args) {
    let tabView = <TabView>args.object;
    if(tabView.selectedIndex == 0){
        this.title = this.test;
        this.routerExtensions.navigate(['tabs',
            {
                outlets: {'test': ['test'],
            }
        }], { 
            clearHistory: true 
         });
    }
    else if(tabView.selectedIndex == 1){
        this.title = this.test1;
        this.routerExtensions.navigate(['tabs',
            {
                outlets: {'test1': ['test1'],
            }
        }], { clearHistory: true });
    }
    else if(tabView.selectedIndex == 2){
        this.title = this.test2;
        this.routerExtensions.navigate(['tabs',
            {
                outlets: {'test2': ['test2'],
            }
        }], { clearHistory: true });
    }
    else if(tabView.selectedIndex == 3){
        this.title = this.notifications;
        this.routerExtensions.navigate(['tabs',
            {
                outlets: {'test3': ['test3'],
            }
        }], { clearHistory: true });
    }
    else if(tabView.selectedIndex == 4){
        this.title = this.settings;
        this.routerExtensions.navigate(['tabs',
            {
                outlets: {'test4': ['test4'],
            }
        }], { clearHistory: true });
    }
}
```

Then in each tab I have other views with other actionbars. When changing tab the history is canceled so if I go back to a previously opened tab, it is recreated and then the actionbar is updated again.

The only problem I found (I think it's a bug) is that (on android) the deletion of the history for router-outlet does not work.

**EDIT**

I had to pass a random parameter to allow the component that I am leaving to call the OnDestroy method so that when I return to the tab I left it, it recreates everything including the actionbar

```
this.routerExtensions.navigate(['tabs',
        {
          parameterForOnDestroy: true
        },
        {
            outlets: {'test': ['test'],
        }
    }], { 
        clearHistory: true 
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't keep separate action bar for each tab, but you can try updating action bar while switching between tabs.